# Error on React-Native Android hardaware BackButton click "Undefined is not a function(evaluating '_this2.close()') "

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have installed the **react-native-orientation-loading-overlay** package for applying the loader on the screen. 
When user clicks on the hardware back button, the backAndroid's addEventListener is called. Depending on the condition, loader's animating property is set to true and the orientation loader starts loading. 
While loading, the another function `this.fetchData()` is started running which fetches data by running the webservice and display in listview of same page i.e mainPage.
And while loading, if the user has again pressed the back button the red screen with the error "Undefined is not a function(evaluating `_this2.close()`) in onRequestClose method of react-native-orienation-loading-overlay\src\index.js file" displays .I have tried to `BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {});` after the loader's animating property is set to true but its not 
working.
Please give me any solution.

```
  import OrientationLoadingOverlay from 'react-native-orientation-loading-overlay';


   <OrientationLoadingOverlay
     visible={this.state.animating}
     color="#6495ed"
     indicatorSize="large"
     messageFontSize={16}
     message="Loading..."
   />
```

My hardware backbutton click event listener code is as follows:

```
   BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
     if(this.state.drawerState===true) {
       this.refs['draw'].closeDrawer();
     } else {
       if(this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length===1&&
         this.state.tagPressed===false){
         if (stack.length===0){
           Alert.alert(
             'Exit',
             'Are you sure?',
             [
               {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {return true;}},
               {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => BackAndroid.exitApp()},
             ],
           )
         } else {
           this.backButtonEvent();
         }
       } else {
         if(this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length===1&&
           this.state.tagPressed===true) {
           this.setState({ animating: true });
           this.setState({ tagPressed: false });
           this.setState({ title: 'Repository' });
           this.fetchData();
         } else {
           this.props.navigator.pop();
         }
       }
     }
     return true;
   });
```

Here the `stack.length` is the length of array of navigated routes. And my `backButtonEvent()` function is as follows:

```
   backButtonEvent() {
     if(stack.length===0) {
       this.refs['draw'].openDrawer();
     } else{
       this.setState({animating:true});
       dirPath = stack.pop();
       title = this.titleStack.pop();
       if(stack.length===0) {
         this.setState({srcUrl:require('../image/drawer1.png')});
         this.setState({drawerLock:'unlocked'});
       }
       this.fetchData();
     }  
   }

 <ListView 
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={(this.renderItem.bind(this))}
   enableEmptySections = {true}
 />  

fetchData(data){
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the line 82 of [source code of the react-native-orientation-loading-overlay](https://github.com/fukuball/react-native-orientation-loading-overlay/blob/master/src/index.js), it uses the function `this.close()` to close the **Modal** but when refer to the [RN 0.41 Documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.41/docs/modal.html), `this.close()` is not pre-defined function for Modal, therefore it triggered the mentioned error when `typeof this.props.children === 'undefined'`. It is a bug for the package. It might have new state to control the on/off of the Modal, and allow this.close() function to change the state to off the Modal.

Comment: This was really helpful . I declared a function 'close()' inside index.js file of the react-native-orientation-loading-overlay package. So it works fine for me.